# Extend bottom border to the right side

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to move just the bottom border to the side (to the right side in my example). I have pictures on the left side of my page, I want to have `<h3>` headings on the right side of these individual pictures. Also I would like to underline these headings with border-bottom property. This border should be 66% of the site long and it should start under `<h3>` heading an go to the right only (without crossing the picture).

[image]

My HTMLis:

```
<figure>
  <img src="Fotky/Neonka.jpg" alt="Tetra neonová"/>
  <figcaption>Tetra neonová</figcaption>
</figure>
<h3>Tetra Neonová</h3>
```

My CSS is:

```
figure {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
figcaption { 
    text-align: center;
}
h3 {  
  border-bottom: solid;
  width: 66%;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you would like to achieve? Some sort of design?

Comment: I added a picture. Hope that it will help a little.

Comment: I've posted the solution below. Let me know in case you need more clarification on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to style h3 as `float: left;` with `width: 66%` and use `h3::after` pseudo-element.

The main advantage of this solution that you can animate any attribute of this element. Try to move mouse over this caption.

```css
body   {
  background-color: rgba(7,17,21,1.00);
  font-family:Cambria, Hoefler Text, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.StickyTop {
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1.MainHeader   {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 56px;
}

.MenuBar   {
  margin-top: -21px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(7,17,21,1.01);
}
.MenuBar a {
  color: lightblue;
}
figure   {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: auto 0;
}
figure img {
  width: 100%;
}
figcaption   { 
  text-align: center;
}
h3 {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h3:after {
  content: " ";
  background: #0000eB;
  width: 66%;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
p {
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="StickyTop">
      <h1 class="MainHeader">Rybičky</h1> 

     <div class="MenuBar">
      <a  class="button1" href="#">Hlavní stránka</a>
      <a  class="button2" href="#">Akvárium</a>
      <a  class="button3" href="#">Rostliny</a>
      <a  class="button4" href="#">odkazy</a>
     </div>
    </div>
<figure>
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-7GEV-jl3XPQ/VjqUuXtUU8I/AAAAAAAAesM/SeF8ECLt3qk/s1600/Cardinal-Tetra.jpg" alt="Tetra neonová"/>
  <figcaption>Tetra neonová</figcaption>
</figure>
<h3>Tetra Neonová</h3>
<p>Here comes the descripton.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet<br> Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor ametHere comes the descripton. Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet<br> Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor ametHere comes the descripton. Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet<br> Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
```

Comment: Wow, i will try it as soon as i get home. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hello again, thank you for the reply. Your solution works nicely. I have only problem now, when I start writing ordinary paragraphs, they are on the left side of the heading (because of float-left atribute I know). I want to have them under the heading and on thle left side of the picture. I tried br clear-both but this doesn't work. Is there a way?

Comment: can't guess what you mean. "on thle left side of the picture"? right? paragraph comes after `</h3>`?

Comment: Ahhh sry my bad, on the right side of the Picture of course. It should looks like: Picture->on the right side of the Picture should be heading (like you made it)->under the heading but still on the right side of the picture I would like to have paragraph(with fish description etc.) Now all my paragraphs are on the right of the heading.

Comment: Weird. H3 In the answer stretched from `figure` to far right of screen. It can't get any element on the right of it. Could you share whole code? I've appended paragraph in the snippet. It seems to look well.

Comment: I think you might put <p>...</p> inside of <h3>...</h3>.That affects the issue. Try to put `p` _after_ heading.

Comment: I was wondering why your code runs excelently and mine not and I figured that if I change width of the Figure (32% in your example, but i don't want so large Picture so I aded width:150px ) paragraphs start positioning on the left side of the heading. So I have to add <br> between heading and paragraph (actually two <br> but i think that this depends on the size of the Picture) to position paragraphs under the heading. Is there a way how to solve this without <br> please?

Comment: Could you share whole code? you also can validate your html on https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I added my code and css to the answers, because it was too long for comments.

Comment: where? I can't see

Comment: since you've limited image size by 150px, common width (img+h3) became narrower than 100%, thus you need to change width of h3 as it should keep a whole space after `figure`, so just set `width: calc(100% - 150px);` to h3. Also I fixed html typos a little. Have a look.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your time and help. Everything looks really nice now. I really appreciate your effort to help me. I hope you will do well.

Comment: You're welcome! :) That's all because I love fish :)

Answer (score 0):

```
figure{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
img{
  max-width: 100px;
}
figcaption   { 
  text-align: center;
}
h3 {  
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: solid;
  width: 66%;
  float: left;
}
```

Align your figure and h3 as inline by mentioning inline-block in their display property. Display block stretched the element horizontally and removes other elements which are placed inline with that element.

Also, you need to align h3 as inline-block because, by default, h3 is a block level element.

Check this fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6uLpb8s/)

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your time and help. It is nicely working :)

Comment: No issues brother...Happy to help you... :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Rybičky a další obyvatelé akvária</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Rybicky.css" />

</head>
<body>
  <div class="StickyTop">
      <h1 class="MainHeader">Rybičky</h1> 

     <div class="MenuBar">
      <a  class="button1"href="#"Hlavní stránka</a>
      <a  class="button2"href="#">Akvárium</a>
      <a  class="button3"href="#">Rostliny</a>
      <a  class="button4"href="#">odkazy</a>
     </div>
    </div>
     <br style="clear:both">
      <figure>
       <img src="Fotky/Neonka.jpg" alt="Tetra neonová"/>
       <figcaption>Tetra neonová</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <h3>Tetra Neonová - <i>Paracheirodon innesi</i></h3>
      <br><br>
        <p>Description of the fish etc. </p>





</body>
</html>
```

and my css:

```
  body   {
 background-color: rgba(7,17,21,1.00);
 font-family:Cambria, Hoefler Text, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
 color: white;

 }

.StickyTop    {
margin-top: -20px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}

h1.MainHeader   {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -12px;
    margin-right: -12px;
    height: 56px;

}

.MenuBar   {

  margin-top: -21px;
   text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(7,17,21,1.01);
}
 figure   {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: auto 0;
 }
 figure img {
width: 100%;
 }
 figcaption   { 
 text-align: center;
 }
 h3{
width: 66%;
text-align: left;
float: left;
margin-top: 0;
padding: 0 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 h3:after {
content: " ";
background: #0000eB;
width: 66%;
height: 2px;
display: block;
position: relative;
 }
```